# BrainTree node integration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, braintree

I have the most Odd problem I have ever had. I just simple cannot find what is wrong with my code.

this is my  user model

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
firstName: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
lastName: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
address: {
    street: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    city: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    state: {type: String, min: 2, max: 2, required: false},
    zipCode: {type: String, required: true, trim: true}
},
customerId: String,
subscription: {
    id: String,
    status: String,
    planId: String,
    price: Number,
    nextBillingDate: Date
},
creditCard: {
    token: {type: String, required: true}
},
email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true, trim: true},
password: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
phone: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
birthDate: {type: Date, required: true, trim: true},
role: {staff: Boolean, admin: Boolean, sAdmin: Boolean},
companies:[
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Company',
        required: true
    }
],
edited: {type: Date},
created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

Now im creating a User Admin on my application with this code.

```
      // BrainTree API
    var nonce = req.body.payment_method_nonce;

    gateway.customer.create({
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName: user.lastName,
        company: req.body.compName,
        email: req.body.email,
        paymentMethodNonce: nonce
    }, function (err, result) {

        if(err) return handleError(err);


        //NO ERROR FOUND
        user.customerId = result.customer.id;

            gateway.subscription.create({
                paymentMethodToken: result.customer.paymentMethods[0].token,
                planId: 'myId'
            }, function (err, result) {
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
                else {

                    //save subscription info
                    user.subscription.id = result.subscription.id;
                    user.subscription.status = result.subscription.status;
                    user.subscription.planId = result.subscription.status;
                    user.subscription.price = result.subscription.price;
                    user.subscription.nextBillingDate = result.subscription.nextBillingDate;

                    //transaction info
                    t.id = result.subscription.transactions[0].id;
                    t.amount = result.subscription.transactions[0].amount;
                    t.creditCard.maskedNumber = result.subscription.transactions[0].creditCard.maskedNumber;
                    t.created = result.subscription.transactions[0].createdAt;

                    saveAdmin();

                }

            });
```

now on user.customerId = result.customer.id;

I get this console error "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined", but that is not true. when I do a console.log(result.customer.id) I get the Id. I just don't know why is throwing the error.

I don't know if anybody can help me with this because but you never know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the exact error message? It would be specifically helpful to know  You use the `.id` attribute multiple times so it could be any of them. Also, updating your code with the console.log lines you are talking about (along with their corresponding output) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem the return handleError(err) some how was executing the request twice. so I change the return handleError(err) with return console.error(err) and it solved the problem.